# debugging android app in the IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-emulator, intellij-idea

I try to debug/run android apps in the IntelliJ IDEA. But when I run example I get a simple window "Waiting for ADB". Next I get error "ADB not responding. Please, kill «adb.exe» process manually and click 'Retry'". Okay, I kill "adb.exe", reload IDEA, but I get error again. 
About my software: Win 8 Dev Preview. Java last. Android SDK 10-15. IDEA last.